# web-ext: How to run Firefox in dark mode?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-ext

I'm working on a new browser extension and I'm using Mozilla's [web-ext](https://github.com/mozilla/web-ext) tool to test it. I couldn't figure out how to run the test browser in dark mode.

So far I have tried this:

```sh
web-ext run --verbose --pref extensions.activeThemeID=firefox-compact-dark@mozilla.org
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way! Apparently, dark mode is an add-on; not a preference.

First step is to create an empty directory to store our Firefox profile.

```sh
mkdir ../dark-mode-profile
npx web-ext run -p ../dark-mode-profile --keep-profile-changes
```

Then enable dark mode and close Firefox (and hit Ctrl-C if necessary). Since we turned on the `--keep-profile-changes` flag, all the changes we made are now stored in our profile folder.

We can run Firefox with this profile:

```sh
npx web-ext run -p ../dark-mode-profile
```